# Connection Reset Exception while upserting 20k records

Tags: soap-api, java

Can anyone tell me how to resolve the below error while uploading 20k records.but it works fine if it is 10k.

```
AxisFault           
faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException          
faultSubcode:          
faultString: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset           
faultActor:          
faultNode:           
faultDetail:            
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @himanshu. Please help me for how to reslove this issue.

Comment: Is there any way to set connection time. Probably 20K records taking longer time than feasible.

Comment: @Ashwani We are not setting connection time.

Comment: No, if you could increase the connection time then this problem can be resolved otherwise you will have to decrease record numbers

Comment: @Ashwani : I will set the connection time.

Comment: Please let me know if it works!

Comment: @Ashwani It doesn't work .tell me some other solutions

Comment: This is problem with closing of connection before the request processed. You will have to make sure that connection is not closed until the request completed and response received. It is more on Java side in compare to Salesforce